# Building NumPy 1.7.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, build, numpy

I'm a newby in both Ubuntu and Python, so please bear with me. I need some functionality included in **NumPy 1.7.1**. My Ubuntu 12.04 LTE, however, comes with **NumPy 1.6.x**, and *sudo apt-get update* doesn't get it any higher.

So I went to sourceforge and followed the instructions given [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.7.0/) in **userguide.pdf**. I have made up to:

> python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95

, i.e. I have (from what it seems like, successfully) built NumPy 1.7.1. The question is: what do I do now? Should I move some directories somewhere, if yes, where? The *userguide.pdf* just stops here and doesn't give any more information.

This is the first time, I'm ever trying this, so please be kind ;-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I install some python package from source I usually do

```
python setup.py build [options]
python setup.py install --user
```

The last step install the package in ~/.local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/. This directory is scanned before the system directories (so this version is used). Furthermore you don't need sudo and you don't risk to mess up with what apt installs

Comment: FYI [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) is a very useful tool for creating 'throwaway' local Python environments that are isolated from the system-wide Python. I tend to use it in combination with [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for convenience.

Comment: @ali_m: virtualenvwrapper seems very interesting. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

If you need to upgrade NumPy to a newer version (not 1.7.1 specifically), you can use `pip`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install numpy --upgrade
```

It will install NumPy 1.8.1 on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
import numpy
numpy.version.version
>>> '1.8.1'
```