# Upgrade to numpy 1.8.0 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, installation, upgrade

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 which comes by default with `NumPy 1.6.0` (I have, actually *had*, `Python 2.7.3` installed). As a result of the answer to this question [polyfit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'w'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838579/polyfit-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-w), I need to upgrade it.

I downloaded the `.tar.gz` package for the version `1.8.0` from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/), unpacked it, moved inside the folder and run the commands:

```
python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95
python setup.py install --user
```

as described in the [user guide](http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/numpy/NumPy/1.8.0/userguide.pdf) and in this question: [Building NumPy 1.7.1 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086706/building-numpy-1-7-1-on-ubuntu).

This resulted in `NumPy` no longer loading in `Spyder`, which now shows the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/scientific_startup.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pylab import *  #analysis:ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 165, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 20, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 52, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/gabriel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: /home/gabriel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode
```

upon loading it. The same happened when I tried with version `1.7.1`.

I tried removing `numpy` with:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-numpy
```

which also removed `matplotlib` and `scipy`. So then I tried reinstalling them with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib
```

but this fails with the error:

```
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

Now I'm left with no running python and I don't even know how to go back to the previous stable version. So the question: can I install at least version `1.7.1` in my system and if not, how do I go back to a working `1.6.0` version? Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
sudo pip install numpy --upgrade
```

will do the same thing with slightly less effort.

Comment: much more standard answer, should get voted above the OP's answer soon, hopefully

Comment: So I have Ubuntu 12.04LTS and Python 2.7.3 and when in Python I ran `numpy.version.version` and found that I had 1.6. I then did your `sudo pip install numpy --upgrade` and with that the numpy1.9 source was downloaded and it did a build. But back in Python 2.7.3 `numpy.version.version` produced... 1.6 (again). No change. So I ran `sudo apt-get build-dep python-numpy`, to get the latest build dependencies straight, and repeated the `--upgrade` build. Same result... 1.6.

Comment: OK, so presumably I goofed here by not realizing that I had started with a Canonical binary, not with a pip build.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, so I tried:

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

which returned:

```
Successfully uninstalled numpy
```

So then I did:

```
pip install numpy
```

but it said:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /home/gabriel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

so apparently it was still there. I removed the contents of that folder and then I simply did:

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

This worked like freaking **magic**. Now I have `NumPy 1.8.0, SciPy 0.12.0, Matplotlib 1.2.1` installed and everything is running like it should.